# Proving that a continuous map of topological spaces induces a homomorphism of fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

I just need a check on this. I feel that the proof is weak, but I want to make sure.

Let $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map of topological spaces. Define $\phi_\ast: \pi_1 (X, x) \rightarrow \pi_1 (Y, \phi(x))$ such that $\phi_\ast ([f]) = [\phi \circ f]$

Consider $\phi_\ast([f]\cdot[g]) = [\phi \circ ([f]\cdot [g])]$. Since $\phi$, $f$, and $g$ are continuous maps, we know that $[\phi \circ ([f]\cdot[g])] = [\phi\circ [f]] \cdot [\phi \circ [g].$

Since $(\phi\circ [f]) \cdot (\phi \circ [g]) = \phi_\ast([f]) \cdot \phi_\ast([g])$, we have shown that $\phi_\ast$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: Can you show that $[f][g] = [fg]$? That is missing in the first step.

Comment: @Gibbs Ah, right. Well, does that not immediately follow from the group structure?

Comment: Yes, but you did not use it. It should be $\phi_*([f][g]) = \phi_*([fg]) = [\phi \circ f \circ g]$. Also, can you prove that $[\phi \circ f \circ g] = [\phi \circ f][\phi \circ g]$? If yes, you are done.

Comment: Yeah, I talked about that last bit with another student. I feel that $[\phi \circ f \circ g] = [\phi \circ f][\phi \circ g]$ follows from the fact that $\phi$ is continuous. Am I wrong, here?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the previous comment: it should be $\phi \circ fg$ and not $\phi \circ f \circ g$. Here $fg$ is the juxtaposition of $f$ and $g$. About your comment: it is a bit more, it follows from the construction of $fg$, that is why I also pointed this out in the first comment. The loop $\phi \circ fg$ is defined as $(\phi \circ fg)(t) = (\phi \circ f)(t)$ when $0 \leq t \leq 1/2$ and as $(\phi \circ g)(t)$ when $1/2 \leq t \leq 1$. So it really is the loop $(\phi \circ f)(\phi \circ g)$, and hence the equality of equivalence classes follows.